# Converting fsocketopen to curl

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I need to convert the following fsocketopen code to curl so I can use a client SSL certificate.  At the moment SSL is turned off so I can get curl working.  Here is the current code slightly amended as it is a secure site.

```
$fp = fsockopen("tcp://XX.XXX.XXX.XX", 5025, $errno, $errstr, 4); 
    if (!$fp) 
    { 
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n"; 
    } 
    else 
    {

            $out = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
           $out .= "<LoginRequest>";
           $out .= "<UserId>". $userID . "</UserId>";
           $out .= "</LoginRequest>";

           $myout = chr(strlen($out)/256);
           $myout .= chr(strlen($out)%256);
           $myout .= $out;

            fwrite($fp, $myout);
            stream_set_timeout($fp,15);

            $in = fread($fp, 11024);
```

This code does work, but if instead of using fread with a value I use

```
while (feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 256);
}
```

It doesn't work as the server never sends an end of file, and never closes the connection (until 3 minutes has passed)

I try to use the following curl, but it just sits there hanging.

```
$url = "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX";
    $port = 5025;

    $out = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
   $out .= "<LoginRequest>";
   $out .= "<UserId>". $userID . "</UserId>";
   $out .= "</LoginRequest>";

   $myout = chr(strlen($out)/256);
   $myout .= chr(strlen($out)%256);
   $myout .= $out;

    // more details at http://php.net/curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myout);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $myout);

    // fetch response and close the socket
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo '<pre>', curl_error($ch) . "\n";

    curl_close($ch);



    echo "response 3 =" . $response;
```

The error I get is 
Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received`enter code here`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure about `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`? It needs to be something like `GET`, `POST` or `CONNECT`. See [php.net](http://php.net/curl_setopt)